# Select2 not working, always displaying "No results found"

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, servlets, jquery-select2

I've tried everything on this site and nothing works, I only want to get the states from a JSON generated by a servlet and then displaying the data on a select bar using AJAX.

But I'm only getting a "No results found" no matter what I type on the select bar.

This is the function to populate the dropdown:

Note: formatRepo and formatRepoSelection are already added

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
    ajax: {
      url: "/socialis/estadoController",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      data: function(params) {
        return {
          q: params.term, // search term
          page: params.page
        };
      },
      processResults: function(data, params) {
        // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
        // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
        // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
        // scrolling can be used
        params.page = params.page || 1;

        return {
          results: data.items,
          pagination: {
            more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
          }
        };
      },
      cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
      return markup;
    }, // let our custom formatter work
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
    templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page

  });
});
```

This is the Servlet doGet method:

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String estados = new Gson().toJson(localizacionDao.getEstados());

        response.getWriter().write(estados);

    }
```

I verified that the JSON was being generated correctly by printing "estados" every time I typed on the Select bar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed:

Basically the JSON format that I was using was wrong, the JSON format that worked for me was:

```
[{"id":7,"text":"Chiapas"},{"id":8,"text":"Chihuahua"}]
```

Also, minor changes to the Select2 function:

```
$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
        ajax: {
          url: "/socialis/estadoController",
          dataType: 'json',
          type: "GET",
          delay: 250,
          data: function (params) {
            return {
              q: params.term, // search term
              page: params.page
            };
          },
          processResults: function (data, params) {
            // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
            // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
            // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
            // scrolling can be used
            params.page = params.page || 1;

            return {
              results: data,
              pagination: {
                more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
              }
            };
          },
          cache: true
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
        minimumInputLength: 1

      });
```

The controller was also changed:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String searchTerm = request.getParameter("q");

    String estados = getOptions(searchTerm);              

    response.getWriter().write(estados);

}
```

It's very important to notice that the filtering of results is done server side, basically Ajax sends a request with the search term, which is named "q", every time you type something in the search bar.

So, in every request the function "getOptions" filter the results like this:

```
public String getOptions(String q){
    List<Estados> estados = localizacionDao.getEstados();
    List<Estados> estadosFiltered = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Estados Estado : estados) {
        if(Estado.getNombreEstado().contains(q)){
            estadosFiltered.add(Estado);
        }
    }
    String estadosString = new Gson().toJson(estadosFiltered);
    System.out.println(estados);
    estadosString = estadosString.replace("idEstado", "id");
    estadosString = estadosString.replace("nombreEstado", "text");
    return estadosString;
}
```

I hope this answer helps.